# Floating percentage width layout

Tags: html, css

I have 4 Divs and want to position them in my page as below:

[image: Desired layout]

I want to add many other svg files to Div 4 later and I want Div 4 to be scrollable. **Notice:** I want only Div 4 be scrollable and not my entire page.

This is how my HTML and CSS looks so far:

```css
#sides {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* contain floated elements */
}
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  height: 60%;
}
.div2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 35%;
}
.div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 15%;
}
.div4 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sides">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: Your implementation is on the right track, but look at the sum of percentages of width of div1 and div2, it exceeds 100% right? Thats why they are not stacking against each other, to make them stack against each other make the width total to be 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example requires a few small tweaks:

- `html,body` and the parent div `#sides` need `height: 100%` in order for their children to have percentage heights.
- The widths and heights of the divs need to add up to 100%. For example, the `.div1` is 75% width, so `.div2`, which sits along side it, needs to be 25% width.
- `box-sizing: border-box` incorporates borders and padding into the width and height of each div. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- The scrolling div is given `overflow-x: scroll` so that its contents will scroll when it overflows, and `white-space: nowrap` prevents inline elements (such as the images in my example) from wrapping. Make sure that any elements inside the div will not be taller than it.

#### Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#sides {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#sides > div {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  /*box-sizing: border-box prevents this padding from blowing out the width and height*/
}
.div1 {
  width: 75%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #E91E63;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 35%;
  background: #9C27B0;
}
.div3 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #2196F3;
}
.div4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background: #009688;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*overflow-x can also be given the value "auto" to only scroll when required*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.div4 > * {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sides">
  <div class="div1">Left</div>
  <div class="div2">Right-top</div>
  <div class="div3">Right-bottom</div>
  <div class="div4">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your div 4 scrollable just define `overflow: scroll` in its CSS, that way the content will hide inside the container instead of flowing out.

Comment: Thanks any idea how to design their design to look similar to what i want?

Comment: Check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/53puh70y/7/ 
I was working with an approx layout, you should define the measurements of the parent container when using percentages.

Answer (score 1):

Now as to this question. Bahador, try using "position:absolute;" in the CSS for each of your DIVs. When you do that, you can individually specify "top" and "left" coordinates for each DIV. In short, you can make a table-like structure. You can do something similar with "position:fixed;" and "position:relative;", each having its own individual positioning characteristics.

As to scrolling... the simplest way to make one DIV scrollable is to populate it with more content than can fit within it. Likewise, the simplest way to make one non-scrollable is to populate it with ***no more*** content than will fit within it.

Comment: Please don't place off-topic comments in answers. Use the comment thread on the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for this, check it out: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLpnk542/)

```
.div4 {
    overflow:auto;
 }
```

Just put the overflow property to auto for a scrollbar( auto will make a scrollbar appear whenever needed) and put hidden for the other divs to clip the content and hide the scrollbar.

Also,I edited the percentages in your code(in the JSfiddle) a bit because you are exceeding 100% width and thats why the div2 and div3 werent getting stacked against each other.

Answer (score 0):

simply define  `overflow: scorll` which clips the content but adds a scrollbar to see the rest of the content.

See this pen for an example:

http://codepen.io/xPetrus/pen/rOOzWR

Answer (score 0):

change a bit your CSS and html,

```
#sides {
width: 100%;
font-size: 12px;
height:100%;
position:absolute;        
background:red;
/* contain floated elements */
}
.div1 {      
width: 60%;
height: 60%; 
float:left;
background:pink;  
}
.div2 {
background:green;  
float: left;
width: 40%;
height:40%;      
}
.div3 {  
height:20%;
float:left;
width: 40%;background:blue;    
}
.div4 {         
overflow-x:scroll;
width: 100%;
height: 40%;background:yellow;     
}
#div4{    
width:180% !important;    
height:auto;
}
```

## html

```
  <div id="sides">
     <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
     <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
     <div class="div3">Div 3</div>
     <div class="div4"><div id="div4">Div 4 Div 4 Div 4</div></div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qykfv6Lp/2/embedded/result/